# Checking if event target has a specific ancestor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check whether the element that is clicked on has a specific ancestor.

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
  var ele = $(e.target);
  console.log(ele.parents('.datepicker').length > 0);
}
```

This outputs:

```
<td class="active">24</td>
false
```

But if I, in the console, do

```
$('td.active').parents('.datepicker').length > 0
```

it outputs

```
true
```

The output of `$(e.target);` is: `[td.active, context: td.active]` which isn't what I would expect, so I think the problem lies here: `var ele = $(e.target);`  but I cant work out what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
console.log($(e.target).parents('.datepicker').length > 0);
```

Or

```
console.log($(ele).parents('.datepicker').length > 0);
```

Edit:
closest() gives true. pls check this

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gkeftw32/)

Comment: Both of those output false

Answer (score 0):

Try `closest()`:

<strike>console.log($(this).closest('.datepicker').length > 0);</strike>

Assuming `datepicker` is within table:

```
console.log($(this).closest('tr').find('.datepicker').length > 0);
```

OR

```
console.log($(this).closest('table').find('.datepicker').length > 0);
```

Comment: Tried it with `this` `ele` and `e.target`  and all of the output as false